# How to embed go.mod & go.sum in go 1.16

Tags: go, embed, go-modules

I want to embed a sub module directory in parent module, but golang remind me that `pattern tpl/api_new/*: cannot embed file tpl/api_new/README.md: in different module`

I know that I can delete go.mod & go.sum and then run "go mod init && go get -u" when the new project is generated.

The bottom is the file tree and the embed variable, is there anything others I can do to embed go.mod & go.sum?
Thanks~

```golang
//go:embed tpl/api_new/*
var apiNew embed.FS
```

```golang
├─api_new
│  │  .editorconfig
│  │  .gitignore
│  │  generate.go
│  │  go.mod
│  │  go.sum
│  │  makefile
│  │  README.md
│  │
│  ├─cmd
│  │  └─app
│  │          main.go
│  │
│  ├─config
│  │      config-dev.toml
│  │      config-live.toml
│  │      config-local.toml
│  │      config-prod.toml
│  │      config-stress.toml
│  │      config-trunk.toml
│  │
│  └─internal
│      └─app
│          ├─http
│          │  │  server.go
│          │  │
│          │  └─example
│          │          hello.go
│          │
│          ├─lib
│          │  ├─err
│          │  │      codecommon.go
│          │  │      err.go
│          │  │
│          │  ├─pms
│          │  │      init.go
│          │  │
│          │  └─util
│          │          md5.go
│          │          url.go
│          │
│          ├─model
│          │  │  init.go
│          │  │
│          │  ├─grpc
│          │  │  ├─roomaggregation
│          │  │  │      aggregation.proto
│          │  │  │      base.go
│          │  │  │
│          │  │  ├─roombase
│          │  │  │      base.proto
│          │  │  │      roombase.go
│          │  │  │
│          │  │  └─roomlist
│          │  │          base.proto
│          │  │          icon.go
│          │  │
│          │  ├─hrpc
│          │  │  │  init.go
│          │  │  │
│          │  │  └─efs
│          │  │          efs.go
│          │  │          init.go
│          │  │          option.go
│          │  │
│          │  └─redis
│          │      ├─attachInfo
│          │      │      index.go
│          │      │
│          │      ├─outing
│          │      │      index.go
│          │      │
│          │      ├─roomcity
│          │      │      roomcity.go
│          │      │
│          │      └─roomjump
│          │              index.go
│          │
│          └─service
│              │  init.go
│              │
│              └─example
│                      hello.go
```

Comment: Do you just want to embed the go.mod file? or do you want to embed the whole tree?

Answer (score 0):

Each module within a repository is stored separately within the [module cache](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-cache). By design, the presence of a `go.mod` file in a subdirectory causes that entire subtree to be completely pruned out of the outer module.

If you really need the individual files in `tpl/api_new` to be accessible to the module in the parent directory, then you can either:

1. remove the inner `go.mod` and `go.sum` files to put the source files all in the same module, or
2. export the `embed.FS` data from some package within the `…/tpl/api_new` module (perhaps an [`internal` package](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages)), and `import` that package in the parent-directory module in order to access that data programmatically.

Answer (score -3):

> is there anything others I can do to embed go.mod & go.sum?

No.